# How can I root my Android on my Mac?

Tags: rooting, macos

I've been looking into rooting my Android phone, which is a ZTE Score. The only way I've found so far is to use the ZergRush tool (Or something like that..)
But I believe it can only be used on a Windows based computer.. Anyway, I have a MacBook Pro which runs an Intel cpu, and I'm running Snow Leopard. Is there a way to root my phone using my Mac?

Comment: Can you post how you got this to work (or maybe accept my answer using the checkmark below the voting buttons if that's what did it)?  Valid questions should stay undeleted and ideally gain an accepted answer so that others can find the question and solution.

Comment: I just borrowed a PC for a few minutes.. But I'm not sure that it worked, I may try your solution.

Comment: Ah I see.  If you don't that's OK, and you definitely don't need to accept an answer without verifying, but again hopefully this question can help others :)

Comment: Yeah, I tried it.. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I searched for that one click root tool and found a post in XDA's Amaze 4G forum that has a Mac version.  I would expect it to be the same as for the ZTE Score, you can try it out anyways: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1310115

Answer (score 0):

It's not a one click solution, but there are solutions depending on what you want to achieve:

- You can install Android SDK and [perform rooting with adb](http://gw2.at/index.php/forum/38-systemgefummel/444-how-to-galaxy-tab-root-manuelle-methode) by using the tools extracted from a one click solution package (the linked instruction uses the tools from a SuperOneClick 1.x package).
- You can use [Heimdall](http://www.glassechidna.com.au/products/heimdall/) (which works fine on a Mac) to install a CyanogenMod ROM. I did this using these [instructions for Samsung Galaxy Tab](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=931857).